# el.getBoundingClientRect is not a function in react odometer js with react visibility sensor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, odometer

I am trying to use react-odometer js with react-visibility-sensor in next js. Here I am getting one err like the image? How can I get rid of this error, Experts please help.
[image]

Here is my code https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-dream-ysi00

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import "odometer/themes/odometer-theme-default.css";
const Odometer = dynamic(import("react-odometerjs"), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => 0
});
import VisibilitySensor from "react-visibility-sensor";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [odometerValue, setOdometerValue] = useState(0);
  const [view, setView] = useState(false);
  const onVisibilityChange = (isVisible) => {
    if (isVisible) {
      setView(true);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOdometerValue(500);
    }, 10);
  }, []);
  return (
    <VisibilitySensor onChange={onVisibilityChange} offset={8} delayedCall>
      <Odometer
        value={view ? odometerValue : 0}
        format="(,ddd)"
        theme="default"
      />
    </VisibilitySensor>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap Odometer in a div, like so

```
<VisibilitySensor onChange={onVisibilityChange} offset={8} delayedCall>
  <div>
    <Odometer
      value={view ? odometerValue : 0}
      format="(,ddd)"
      theme="default"
    />
  </div>
</VisibilitySensor>;
```

you should see '500' rendered.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-fast-y3k4s?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: mind please marking the answer as accepted? So others know this works. Thanks

Comment: Yes, sir. I did it. Thank you very much.